# How to make a dataset similar to that of murchison data in spatstat for ppm and AUc analysis

Tags: spatstat

1. I have four variables: a point process pattern of species
   occurrence, rivers, ponds polygons and land image data. I would like
   to make a dataset similar to that of Murchison dataset using these
   shape layers but I have failed to manoeuvre.

   I need to make a data frame from these polygon shape layers of
   rivers, ponds and land cover images together with the point pattern
   data of species occurrences I tried using a hyper frame but I am
   unable to use a distance function from the river or the ponds.

   rivers <- readShapespatial("river.shp") ponds <-
   readShapeSpatial(pond.shp") fro <- read.table("fro.txt",
   header=TRUE) image <- raster("image.tif")

   I would like to combine
   these four files as a single spatstat object like that of Murchison
   data which comes with spatstat package. if I can put them in a frame
   then ponds, land cover, rivers are covariates.

   I have used analyst function but return errors that they can not be
   used as covariates, fore example x is a list can not be used as
   covariates particularly for ponds and rivers when I call the dist
   function.

Comment: Welcome! What did you try? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you I tried a.ppp <- ppp(fro, ow, marks=factor(mark@fro$mark)) ponds <- as.owin(ponds) rivers<- as.psp(rivers) landcover <- as.im(image) Then tried to load them into one data frame using hyperframe function hp <- hyperframe ( X=a.ppp, Y= anylist(rivers, landcover, ponds))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need a `hyperframe`? You refer to `murchison` data and that is not
a `hyperframe`. It simply a standard R `list` (with extendend classes
`listof`, `anylist` and `solist` for better printing and plotting in
`spatstat`, but the actual data structure is just a plain `list`).

To recreate the `murchison` data:

```r
library(spatstat)
P <- murchison$gold # Points
L <- murchison$faults # Lines
W <- murchison$greenstone # "Windows

mur <- solist(points = P, lines = L, windows = W)
mur
#> List of spatial objects
#> 
#> points:
#> Planar point pattern: 255 points
#> window: rectangle = [352782.9, 682589.6] x [6699742, 7101484] metres
#> 
#> lines:
#> planar line segment pattern: 3252 line segments
#> window: rectangle = [352782.9, 682589.6] x [6699742, 7101484] metres
#> 
#> windows:
#> window: polygonal boundary
#> enclosing rectangle: [352782.9, 681699.6] x [6706467, 7100804] metres
```

To use the data in a model they don’t have to be collected in a single list,
but it may be convenient. The following two models are identical:

```r
(mod1 <- ppm(P ~ W))
#> Nonstationary Poisson process
#> 
#> Log intensity:  ~W
#> 
#> Fitted trend coefficients:
#> (Intercept)       WTRUE 
#>  -21.918688    3.980409 
#> 
#>               Estimate      S.E.   CI95.lo    CI95.hi Ztest       Zval
#> (Intercept) -21.918688 0.1666667 -22.24535 -21.592028   *** -131.51213
#> WTRUE         3.980409 0.1798443   3.62792   4.332897   ***   22.13252
(mod2 <- ppm(points ~ windows, data = mur))
#> Nonstationary Poisson process
#> 
#> Log intensity:  ~windows
#> 
#> Fitted trend coefficients:
#> (Intercept) windowsTRUE 
#>  -21.918688    3.980409 
#> 
#>               Estimate      S.E.   CI95.lo    CI95.hi Ztest       Zval
#> (Intercept) -21.918688 0.1666667 -22.24535 -21.592028   *** -131.51213
#> windowsTRUE   3.980409 0.1798443   3.62792   4.332897   ***   22.13252
```

If you insist on a `hyperframe` you should have a column for each measured
variable, but these are primarily used for when you have several replications
of an experiment, and is not of much use here. The function call is simply:

```r
murhyp <- hyperframe(points = P, lines = L, windows = W)
```

Comment: Thank you Ege Rubak

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept the answer if it solves your problem so it doesn't show up as unsolved for future readers.

Comment: I have just seen the button you know am new on this platform. Am very sorry about that.